# Terminal velocity of a steel ball in water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, data-analysis, viscosity, estimation

I am investigating on the terminal velocity of steel balls moving in water. I used the balls with different diameters, such as 3.17mm, 6.02mm, etc. And I used a full-filled 1L graduated cylinder. I dropped the ball below the water surface. And I calculate the terminal velocity by a program called Logger Pro.

Theoretically, the terminal velocity of steel ball with diameter 3.17mm in water is about 37m/s. But in my experiment, it is only 0.7m/s. The difference is really huge.

And also, I got a graph of terminal velocity as a function of square of radius of steel ball. It is a straight line, but it does not go through origin.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Did you use any equations to solve the investigation? If so, could you show them?

Comment: I only used Stoke's Law to calculate the theoretical value.

Comment: Maybe your answer was so far off because the Logged data recorded the terminal velocity within the dimensions of the cylinder, where as terminal velocity really can't be reached in such a small area. Or did you take that into account?

Comment: Is the sphere hollow?

Comment: I am sure that they reached the terminal velocity because on my graph of velocity as a function of time, the last part is horizontal. The sphere is solid.

Comment: I'd be extremely surprised (which happens) if terminal velocity was theoretically 37 m/s. Can you supply an expression that shows that ?

Comment: I am also very surprised. I used Stoke's Law, which is terminal velocity = [g*(ρ1-ρ2)*d^2]/18μ. g is gravitational acceleration, ρ1 is the density of ball, ρ2 is the density of medium(in my case, water), d is the diameter of ball, and μ is the dynamic viscosity of medium. I just put in values, and get 37m/s. I also think that theoretical value is wrong, but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Please clarify what your specific question is - "please help me" is not a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stokes Law is not going to apply in this situation because the water flow around the ball will be turbulent not laminar. The way to see this is to calculate the Reynold's number. For a sphere this is approximately given by:

$$ Re \approx \frac{\rho_wdv}{\mu} $$

If we feed in $\rho_w = 1000$ kg/m$^3$, $d = 0.00317$ m, $v = 37$ m/s and $\mu = 0.001$ Pa.s then we get $Re \approx 117290$. A Reynold's number of greater than one means the flow is turbulent, and since Re for a $3.17$ mm ball travelling at $37$ m/s is far greater than one we conclude that the flow is turbulent and Stoke's law doesn't apply.

In a turbulent regime [the viscous drag is given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)):

$$ F_d = \tfrac{1}{2}\rho C_d A v^2 $$

where $\rho$ is the density of the fluid (i.e. water), $A$ is the frontal area of the object, $v$ is the velocity and $C_d$ is a dimensionless parameter called the drag coefficient. The value of $C_d$ depends on the Reynold's number (so it isn't really a constant) but it's generally of order one.

Comment: A = the cross sectional area...

Comment: Strictly speaking $A$ is the *reference area*, which for a sphere is the frontal/cross section area (the two are the same for a sphere).

Comment: How can I get the value of Cd at different times from Reynold's number?

Comment: @Kejia1026: $C_d$ has to be measured experimentally. The values of Cd for a sphere in water are almost certainly available somewhere in Googlespace.

Comment: @JohnRennie You might want to edit a bit regarding Reynolds numbers for turbulence. The transition usually occurs (very approximately) around $5 \cdot 10^5$ (pipe flow being a notable exception). This seems to hold for a [smooth sphere](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/K-12/airplane/dragsphere.html).